# Angular - ClientQuoteLandingComponent.html:74 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'invalid' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am developing an application with Angular-7. I want to populate a select option from the ts and call it in HTML

client-quote-landing.component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, LOCALE_ID, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ClientQuoteService } from '../../../../shared/services/client-quote.service';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-client-quote-landing',
  templateUrl: './client-quote-landing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client-quote-landing.component.scss']
})
export class ClientQuoteLandingComponent implements OnInit {

  quoteModel: any = {};
  truck_types = [];

  constructor(
    private clientQuoteService: ClientQuoteService, private toastr: ToastrService,
    private router: Router,
    @Inject(LOCALE_ID) private locale: string,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {
    this.truck_types = ["Truckbull", "bullion", "bulky"];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));

    // document.body.className = 'skin-blue sidebar-mini';
  }


   onCreateQuote(quoteform: any) {
      if (!quoteform.valid) { // return false if form not valid
        return false;
    }
      this.clientQuoteService.createClientQuote(this.quoteModel)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          if (!response['success']) {
            this.toastr.error(response['message']);
            return false;
          }
          this.toastr.success(response['message']);
          quoteform.reset();
          quoteform.resetForm();
          this.router.navigate(['landing']);
        },
        error => {
          this.toastr.error(error);
        }
      );
   }

getSelectedTrucktype(truck_type: String) {
  console.log("Form this.quoteModel.truck_type" + this.quoteModel.truck_type);
}

}
```

client-quote-landing.html

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
<label for="truck_type">Truck Type</label>
<select placeholder="Select Truck Type" [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.truck_type" name="truck_type" (change)="getSelectedTrucktype(quoteModel.truck_type)">
<option [ngValue]="null">Choose a Truck Type</option>
<option [ngValue]="truck_type" *ngFor="let truck_type of truck_types">{{truck_type}}</option>
 </select>
 <div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="truck_type.invalid && ((truck_type.dirty || truck_type.touched) || quoteform.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
<div style="color:red;" *ngIf="truck_type.errors?.required"class="alert alert-danger">Truck Type is required.</div>
</div>
</div>
```

When I clicked on the select option, it was supposed to display the list of Truck Type, but it was empty. Then, when I checked the console I got this error:

[image: console error]

line 74:

```
 <option [ngValue]="truck_type" *ngFor="let truck_type of truck_types">{{truck_type}}</option>
```

line 77:

```
<div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="truck_type.invalid && ((truck_type.dirty || truck_type.touched) || quoteform.submitted)" class="invalid-feedback">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are referring to form errors, you should not use the `name` value, but mark it with `#someName="ngModel"` as per the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/forms#show-and-hide-validation-error-messages), here I use `#truckType="ngModel"` So add that and use it in your template to check the validity:

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="quoteModel.truck_type" #truckType="ngModel" name="truck_type">
```

and the checks:

```html
<div *ngIf="truckType.invalid && ((truckType.dirty || truckType.touched) || quoteform.submitted)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="truck_type.invalid...">` is outside the `*ngFor` loop which creates the local `truck_type` variable. You need to check the actual variable, making sure it exists:

```html
`<div class="form-feedback" *ngIf="quoteModel.truck_type && quoteModel.truck_type.invalid &&...">`
```

Comment: Will Alexander -  I did as you advised but the error is still there

Comment: I've made a change, forgot to check that the `truck_type` actually exists.